# cleaning multi terms fron stopwords

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of expressions, and I need to remove from these expressions the stopwords.

```
ex = ["andare con i piedi di piombo", "avere gli occhi foderati di prosciutto", 'non chiudere occhio', 'con le mani nel sacco']

stopwords = ["ad","al", "allo", "ai","agli", "all", "alla", "col", "in", "il", "della", "un", "con", "non", "i", "di", "le", "nei", "gli"]
```

I tried this

```
for es in ex:
    new_ex = ''
    for word in stopwords:
         new_es = es.replace(" " +word+ " ", "")
    print(new_es)
```

The above code does not remove the stopwords

Can someone help?

Comment: Break the ex in a list of strings using `ex.split()` and check if word not in stopwords you add it to a new string

Comment: There is no need to ```split()``` the string. ```str.replace()``` can do what the OP wants. The problem is that he is not updating the right variable contents.

Answer (score 0):

using your example

```
ex = ["andare con i piedi di piombo", "avere gli occhi foderati di prosciutto", 'non chiudere occhio', 'con le mani nel sacco']

stopwords = ["ad","al", "allo", "ai","agli", "all", "alla", "col", "in", "il", "della", "un", "con", "non", "i", "di", "le", "nei", "gli"]
```

you could go with:

```
for es in ex:
es = es.split()
new_es = ''
for word in es:
  if word not in stopwords:
      new_es += word + ' '
print(new_es)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
sentences = [
        'andare con i piedi di piombo',
        'avere gli occhi foderati di prosciutto',
        'non chiudere occhio',
        'con le mani nel sacco'
]

words = [
        'ad',
        'al',
        'allo',
        'ai',
        'agli',
        'all',
        'alla',
        'col',
        'in',
        'il',
        'della',
        'un',
        'con',
        'non',
        'i',
        'di',
        'le',
        'nei',
        'gli'
]

for sentence in sentences:
    s = sentence
    for word in words:
        s = s.replace(f' {word} ', '')
    print(s)
```

The problem in your code is that you need to make `new_ex = ex` and use `replace()` on `new_ex`.

Here is the output of the code above:

```
andarei piedipiombo
avereocchi foderatiprosciutto
non chiudere occhio
conmani nel sacco
```

Also note that `'non chiudere occhio'` remains the same because you are looking for a `word` padded by spaces.